# Ubuntu boots to flickering screen with white noise on primary monitor but only with specific Linux kernels - advice on how to fix?

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, nvidia, kernel

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on a dual boot laptop with Windows 10.  There is an external monitor plugged into the HDMI port. I booted to Ubuntu with Linux kernel `5.13.0.27-generic` and it booted correctly until the login screen, where the laptop monitor flashed black and white with white noise, the external monitor showed a purple background.

I rebooted and chose the `5.13.0.25-generic` kernel from the GRUB menu. The first time it booted without issues and I logged in. The second time it did the flickering screen and has done on all subsequent attempts to boot up with this kernel.

I rebooted and used the `5.11.0.46-generic` kernel option from the GRUB and this works consistently. Using this kernel I tried changing the video card driver from *Nvidia driver 470* to *Nvidia driver 495* then *Nvidia driver 460*. Neither of these fixed the issue.

My system's specs are:

- ASUS laptop
- Processor: AMD® Ryzen 7 4800h
- 16 GB RAM
- Video card: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] / GeForce
- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- GNOME version 3.36.8

Windows 10 boots fine and I can use Ubuntu with the `5.11.0.46` kernel. Prior to this happening, the last time I booted into Ubuntu the only change I made to the system was installing Nemo through Ubuntu Software, which I have now uninstalled.

Any advice on how to fix would be greatly appreciated before I try a fresh re-install of Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: I have same issue too on Asus Zephyrus G14, booting back to 5.11 resolves issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the solution to use switchblade graphics mode is to go back to kernel `5.11.0.46` (somehow). If you have a BIOS switch for it, you can select discrete graphics mode. Also, maybe try to connect your laptop with an external monitor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).